# PDFTron: How to suppress page label in PTPDFViewCtrl

Tags: ios, pdftron

Is there a way to suppress the page number (e.g. '1/253') that overlays a page when it appears, and then disappears in a fade animation? It is a UILabel within the PTPDFViewCtrl view, but I can't find anything in the documentation that indicates how to configure it to prevent the label from appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDFNet ships almost all of its UI code as part of the open source "Tools" project. This way you have 100% control over the UI, and aren't dependent on PDFTron exposing hooks to achieve the UI that's perfect for your app. The tools project includes code for everything from annotating to form filling to text selection to... the page number indicator.

To modify (or eliminate) the page number indicator, you can look at where it is set up in the designated initializer for the base tool class, Tool.m, located at `/Lib/src/PDFViewCtrlTools/Tools/Tool.m`, and modify or remove it there.

I work at PDFTron.